# if condition in javascript taking data from xml not working

Tags: javascript, php, xml, rss

I'm having a problem and i don't know what i'm doing wrong.Well,
I'm parsing an `xml` file with `php`.The `if condition`doesn't work for some reason.
Talking about this line: `if (( '<?php echo $item['temp'] ?>' >= "37.0 °C") ) {`
I have no idea why this line is not working.

```
    <?php foreach ( $item_array as $item ) : ?> 

                            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(<?php echo $item['glat']; ?>),
                                                                parseFloat(<?php echo $item['glon']; ?>));

                            if (( '<?php echo $item['temp'] ?>' >= "37.0 °C") ) {
                                alert('<?php echo $item['temp']; ?>');
                                var contentString = '<?php echo $item['title']; ?>' + ' , ' + '<?php echo $item['temp']; ?>' ;
                                var marker1 = createMarker1( contentString,latlng,hot );
                            }
        var hot   = 'weather_icons/hot.png';
        function createMarker1( contentString,latlng,hot ) {
                            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            map: map,
                            icon: hot
                            });
                        google.maps.event.addListener( marker1, "click", function() {
                        if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
                            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: contentString
                            });
                            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
                        });
                        return marker1;
        }
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

A sample of the xml file:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>    
<item>
    <title>Salonika</title>
    <temp>6.7 °C</temp>
    <glat>40.422726139672626</glat>
    <glon>22.93392777442932</glon>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Checking strings with the `>=` operator seems alien to me. Perhaps try `parseInt('<?php echo $item['temp'] ?>', 10) >= '37.0 °C'`

Comment: thanks a lot Tim . I'm gonna take a look on how to compare strings

Comment: @TimVermaelen: `parseInt` would chop off any fractional portion (`parseInt("6.7", 10)` is `6`). Technically as the OP is comparing against a whole number using `>=` that doesn't matter, but `parseFloat` still seems like the more appropriate choice.

Comment: You are right and although my little comment may work if you just compare 37 >= 36 but then again not 37.0 >= 37.5 so `parseFloat` seems more on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing *strings*, not numbers. The *string* `"6.7 °C"` is greater than the *string* `"37.0 °C"`. When [comparing strings](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5), JavaScript compares them "character" by "character" (technically, they're not characters but *code units* in UTF-16, but that's a technical detail). The character `"6"` is greater than the character `"3"`, so the comparison doesn't have to look any further; it knows that the string starting with `"6"` is "greater than" the string starting with `"3"`.

I would recommend modifying the PHP to output a number rather than a string. But if you want to leave the PHP as it, you can deal with this in the JavaScript:

```
if ( parseFloat('<?php echo $item['temp'] ?>') >= 37 ) {
```

`parseFloat` will parse the beginning of the string into a number (it assumes base 10), stopping at the first non-number character (in this case, the space). Note that I've changed what it's comparing to, as well, and gotten rid of the extra `()` (they were harmless, but pointless).

Comment: +1 and a reference for parseFloat():  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: I have to leave the php.I use the line you wrote and it works great!Thanks!